Baking Ambient Occlusion map gives triangulated artifacts
I am trying to Bake an Ambient Occlusion map for use in UE5. The imported Model is a brain scan so it is fairly complex. But I am experiencing these black triangulated artifacts. I have tried unwrapping the UVs in different ways, I have tried subdividing the mesh to give it more resolution, but when baking the ambient occlusion I somehow always get these errors as in the image

Here's the file:


Have you checked your model for consistent normals?

Hi! I have looked at the normals, and they weirdly enough seem fine. I have tried unifying them as well. The strange thing is that it very much looks like a normal issue, but it seems like it is not when I look at the normals. I have tried the Mesh rebuild modifier as well to no avail

Maybe you could share a faulty chunk of your mesh, keeping the size down, on https://blend-exchange.com/

Hey! Here is a blend. file! Thank you for taking a look! 

Thanks, will have a look when I can.. maybe someone else will before me. Shouldn't be too long.

Did you manage to take a look Robin? :)

Hello Håvard ...  Aaaaahhhh! Sorry, I needed the reminder. I think I see the problem: aliasing: https://imgur.com/a/P6YE73T. The shading is interpolated across triangles from the values at their corners.. in this case from very large pixels, relative to face size. Not a specialist area for me.. Having a think. We need some sort of unwrapping thet wil preserve continuity between faces in visible areas, possibly, somehow, with seams down the bottoms of fissures.
